# Java Pattern.quote("\\d c pb sddsf \n"); Why

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Why `\n` does not get printed out?

```
System.out.println(Pattern.quote("\\d c pb sddsf \n"));
```

Basically everything gets printed out apart `\n`. Any clue? It should "literalize" the whole string, shouldn't it?

As it says [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given
>   no special meaning.

Comment: `\n` its for newline escape char. try `\\n`

Comment: "\\d" isn't printed out as is either. It (unfortunately) comes out "\d".

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is a valid java escape character, escape it with a backslash to treat it as a normal character.:

```
    System.out.println(Pattern.quote("\\d c pb sddsf \\n"));
```

Comment: well they should have specified it in the javadoc. As it is stated it seems that any escape sequence will be literalized.

Answer (score 0):

This is working exactly as it supposed to do. Probably you are getting confused because of the output you are looking at. Lets Consider following example for more details

```
 System.out.println(Pattern.quote("First part \t Second part \n Third part"));
```

**The output for following would be**

```
 \QFirst part        Second part   
  Third part\E
```

At start and end of string it `\Q` means "start of literal text" (ie regex "open quote")
`\E` means "end of literal text" (ie regex "close quote") which means it turns the string into regex literals.

`First part \t Second part` In this part these two text part were get separated by tab space, that means its there as it supposed to be in string presentation.

`\n Third part` this printed on next line by using newline escape sequence.

If you want to see those escape sequences then your have to use `\` but in that case they would be simply considered as string and not as escape chars.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.quote("First part \\t Second part \\n Third part"));
```

**Output for above would come out**

```
\QFirst part \t Second part \n Third part\E
```

For more clarification, let find out output of following

```
String esc = "\t";
String pat = Pattern.quote(esc);
String [] str = "First part      Second part \t Third Part".split(pat);
for(String n : str){
   System.out.println(n + " :: " + pat);
    }

esc = "\\t";
pat = Pattern.quote(esc);
str = "First part   Second part \t Third Part".split(pat);
for(String n : str){
   System.out.println(n + " :: " + pat);
}
```

Now for `esc = "\t";` it will split the string while `esc = "\\t";` it wont as split method unable to find anything `\t` as string (which we think supposed to work, but not because of quote() method).

**See output.**

```
First part  :: \Q   \E
 Second part  :: \Q \E
 Third Part :: \Q   \E
First part  Second part      Third Part :: \Q\t\E
```